# Connect views.py to a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm working on a `Django` project showing PDF files from a dummy database. I have the function below in `views.py` to show the PDF files.

```
def pdf_view(request):
    try:
        with open ('static/someData/PDF', 'rb') as pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=test1.pdf'
            return response
        pdf.closed
    except ValueError:
        HttpResponse("PDF not found")
```

This function needs get connected to another function located in a javascript file.

How do we connect `views.py` to another Javascript file?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to `"connect"`. `JavaScript` can use `fetch(url, ...).then(response => {...}).catch(error => {...})` to send request and get response.

Comment: if you use `with open(...) as ...` then you don't need `pdf.closed` (or rather `pd.close()`) because `with` will automatically close it. BTW: `pdf.closed` is after `return` so it will be NEVER executed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. :)  The reason that I need to connect views.py to Javascript is that in Javascript there's another function called "check_files". Which checks if the files in the database are PDFs or not. If the file is a PDF then we need to call def pdf_view(request) to show the PDF content.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I added an "Iframe tag" in the JavaScript file. Then there was no need to use the "def pdf_view(request)" function.